# Run an executable with no file extension with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10

I would like to run Application.exe as an exe file within Python, but **Application.exe** would have a different file extension,  for example: **"Application.example"**, or no extension at all: **"Application"**

Similarly to opening tar archives without the correct tar file extension:

```
tarfile.open("archive.tar.example", "w:gz")
```

The executable in question would need to keep it's current working directory for dependancies, and has a GUI (not terminal output based)

Is it possible to do this with Python 3 on Windows 10?

Comment: rename .example to .exe, run it, rename it back?

Comment: It is not possible to rename the application, I want to keep the same filename and extension and run it as if it had the .exe file extension

Comment: What have you tried? `subprocess.Popen` calls WinAPI `CreateProcessW`, which will execute a PE binary regardless of the file extension.

Comment: That worked, thank you. I didn't know that Popen could execute a file with no file extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Eryk Sun

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("Application.example")
```